# DOTALL for String.matches()

Tags: java, regex, string

I know that DOTALL is available for the fully fledged Pattern+Matcher classes.

But if I want to only use [`String.matches()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), is there a way to tell it to use the DOTALL modifier?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can enable it with the embedded flag `(?s)`, as in

```
"\n".matches("(?s)."); // true
```

Here's the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).

Comment: +1 I totally forgot this one.. Added this to my answer just to avoid confusion.

Comment: I had the same problem, and cleared it with your answer so +1