# How to match regex over multiple lines

Tags: java, regex, newline

I have a body of text and I am trying to find a character sequence within it. `String.contains()` will not work so Im trying to use `String.matches` method and a regular expression. My current regex isn't working. Here are my attempts:

```
"1stline\r\n2ndline".matches("(?im)^1stline$"); 
// returns false; I expect true

"1stline\r\n2ndline".matches("(?im)^1stline$") 
// returns false

"1stline\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdline".matches("(?im)^2ndline$")   

"1stline\n2ndline\n3rdline".matches("(?im)^2ndline$")

"1stline\n2ndline\n3rdline".matches("(?id)^2ndline$")
```

How should i format my regex so that it returns true?

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you're trying to match?

Comment: @Steve P thanx for the comment. I'll modify my question.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3651725/778118) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7911362/778118).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use the `s` flag (not the `m` flag).

It's called the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) option.

This works for me:

```
  String input = "1stline\n2ndLINE\n3rdline";
  boolean b = input.matches("(?is).*2ndline.*");
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911567/778118).

Note you must use `.*` before and after the regex if you want to use [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29).

That's because [`String.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) attempts to match the *entire* string with the pattern.

(`.*` *means zero or more of any character when used in a regex*)

---

Another approach, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652392/778118):

```
  String input = "1stline\n2ndLINE\n3rdline";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)2ndline", Pattern.DOTALL);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
  boolean b = m.find();
  print("match found: " + b);
```

I found it by googling [`"java regex multiline"`](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=java%20regex%20multiline&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and clicking the [first result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652392/778118).

(*it's almost as if that answer was written just for you...*)

There's a ton of info about patterns and regexes [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

---

If you want to match **only if** `2ndline` appears at the **beginning of a line**, do this:

```
   boolean b = input.matches("(?is).*\\n2ndline.*");
```

Or this:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\n2ndline", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see if `"1stLine"` exists within the string `"1stline\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdLine"` then you could just do the following:

```
String test1= "1stline\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdLine";
System.out.println(test1.contains("1stline"));
//returns true
```

**----------------------------EDIT----------------------------**

So for some reason .contains wont work in your test. Here is the regular expression to find the string "1stline"

```
    String regex = "([\\r\\n]|.)*(1stline)+([\\r\\n]|.)*";

    String test1= "1stline\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdLine";
    System.out.println(test1.contains("1stline"));
    //returns true

    String test2 = "1stline\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdLine";
    System.out.println(test2.matches(regex));
    //returns true

    String test3 = "1stline\r\n";
    System.out.println(test3.matches(regex));
    //returns true

    String test4 = "1stline";
    System.out.println(test4.matches(regex));
    //returns true

    String test5 = "\r\n2ndline\r\n3rdLine";
    System.out.println(test5.matches(regex));
    //returns false

    String test6 = "n2ndlinen2ndlinen2ndline\r\n2ndline\r\n4rdLine";
    System.out.println(test6.matches(regex));
    //returns false
```

Comment: thanx for you answer. But just to make it clear, Im looking for a word between `\r\n`'s in a multiline string. Im not looking for the `\r\n` itself

Comment: In other words, you want to return the words between "\r\n" ?

Comment: My bad. I mean I want to know if such word exists.

Comment: So if the string "1stLine" exists on any line?

Comment: @Arvin I edited my question. Take a Look.

Comment: Ok, my bad again. I want to know if the line exist. Said line could be the 1st line or the last line or anywhere inside the string. `String.contains` just wouldn't do it. thanx for your patience.

Comment: @Arvin edited once more. Take a look

Comment: Rather than build a complicated regex with platform-dependant newline characters, you can just use `(?s)` to enable [`DOTALL mode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL).  Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825571/778118).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `contains`

It would be something like

```
yourString.contains("(.+\\r\\n)+(.)+(wordYouAreLookingFor)");
```

btw, using same example that @wdziemia, I'm not expert at REGEX either... :)

hope it helps.