# Jenkins conditional run step not matching

Tags: regex, plugins, jenkins

I'm trying to run a Jenkins build step based on a conditional regular expression match and I can't figure out why it doesn't match.

Here's how it looks in Jenkins:
[image]

I'm using this regular expression: `.*iOS.` against a build parameter, pmt_content.

Here's the pmt_content value:

```
<body><pre>^1234567890^abc123def132afd1213afas^iOS^Test User^test@abc.com^iPad 3^</pre><img src='https://cirrus.app47.com/notifications/5626a0bc9ac25b6ea7003f2f/img' alt=''/></body>
```

Here's the console log telling me it did not match.

```
[PollMailboxTrigger] An email matching the filter criteria was found. (log)
Building in workspace /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/New Device Listener/workspace
Run condition [Regular expression match] enabling prebuild for step [Execute shell]
Regular expression run condition: Expression=[.*iOS.*], Label=[
<body><pre>^1234567890^abc123def132afd1213afas^iOS^Test User^test@abc.com^iPad 3^</pre><img src='https://cirrus.app47.com/notifications/5626a0bc9ac25b6ea7003f2f/img' alt=''/></body>]
Run condition [Regular expression match] preventing perform for step [Execute shell]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Clearly pmt_content contains "iOS".

I tested the same values at www.regexplanet.com.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I experienced similar frustrations due to a newline character in my label data which prevented a match.  Hard to tell from your dump if there might be a newline in there at the start.  In any event you might try `(?is).*iOS.*`.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17825571/1588506).