# trying to find comments in multiline text (specific text after '#')

Tags: java, regex, multiline

I have a multiline file which I read into a `String`. In this `String` I need to find rows which are commented.

for example, from the following text:

```
#................... EPCT Product level setting ................................#......
export EPCT_PRODUCT="OMS"
#export SRC_DB=CHR81/CHR81@CHROMSE9    # EPC/Ref DB source connect string
#export TAR_DB=OMS1OMS/OMS1OMS@CHRDB454  # EPC/Ref DB target
```

I would like to find `#export SRC_DB`

For this i wrote the following regex: `.*#\\s*export\\s+SRC_DB.*`

When I tested it with a single line of text, it matched:

```
//this will return true:
"#export SRC_DB=CHR81/CHR81@CHROMSE9    # EPC/Ref DB source connect string".matches(".*#\\s*export\\s+SRC_DB.*")
```

But when trying to mach the multiline string, it doesn't match:

```
//this returns false
theFullText.matches(".*#\\s*export\\s+SRC_DB.*")
```

I've tried to add the `(is)` expression to the regext, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824211/how-to-match-regex-over-multiple-lines)e, but it still doesnt match:

```
//this also returns false
theFullText.matches("(is).*#\\s*export\\s+SRC_DB.*")
```

Comment: A dot does not match a newline symbol in Java without a DOTALL flag. Add a `(?s)` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ2pY6/1)) at the beginning of the pattern.

Comment: indeed `(?s)` or `(?is)` solved the issue. Thanks.