# Regular expression for multi line

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the below code that contains multiple lines.
Code:

> This is India
>
> I am from Mumbai

Is there a way in which I can write regular expression above the lines.
I tried the way below, but it does not match:

> \s*\w*\W*\s*\n\s*\w*\W*

Can anyone help me in writing a regex for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824211/how-to-match-regex-over-multiple-lines

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex  :

```
\r\n
```